# Similar HttpResponse.SubStatusCode (Framework 4.8) in Net Core

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I'm trying to return a status code with subcode (403.8) in a custom AuthorizationFilter in net core application.

With fullframework, I can use HttpResponse.SubStatusCode [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpResponse_SubStatusCode)

There is any option to return substatuscode in net core?

Comment: Since 403.8 is not a standard HTTP status code defined by IIS.  Try add `HttpErrors` config to let it  correctly handled by IIS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191724/1179950

Comment: Why do you want that? The Remarks in the doc page explain that `Independent of whether tracing is configured, the code is never sent as part of the final response to the request`. Sub-status codes are IIS-specific anyway - there are no substatus codes in the HTTP standard

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I try to change the code to differentiate that code from any request that gives the same code. Like a custom code.

Comment: @Zen I see that solution but I'm building a filter and I haven't web.config

Comment: Differentiate where? The substatus code is never sent to the caller, it's only logged and displayed in the YSOD. You can log whatever you want in your code already

Comment: Ok, I thought I could see it in the answer.

Comment: Finally we send diferent statuscode. Lots of thanks for both Zen and Panagiotis